# how to move animation across the screen js

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've created an animation of a pac-man opening and closing its mouth, but i would like to have it move across the screen as well. I've played around with setTimeout() and i can get it one image to go across the screen but not the actual animation. how can i do this using pure JS.

this is the HTML i have

```
<body>
  <div id="animation">
    <img id="pacManImg" src="pacMan1.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <img id="pacManImg" src="pacMan2.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
</div>
<button onclick="startAnimation()"> Start</button>
</body>
```

i'm using this for my js

```
function startAnimation() { 
  var frames = document.getElementById("animation").children;
  var frameCount = frames.length;
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function () { 
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
}, 300);
}
```

Comment: Something like `frames[i % frameCount].style.left = frames[i % frameCount].style.left.slice(0, -2) + "px"`, if the frames are position absolute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `i` to increase the `left` property:

```
setInterval(function() {
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("animation").style.left = i + "px";
});
```

Note that this requires `position: absolute;` in your CSS.

Comment: Beat me by a millisecond (:

Comment: i tried what you suggested but it won't move (like walk across the screen). this is what i have in my css 
 #animation img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
    }
 
 #animation img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
 }  is this correct?

Comment: No, you need the `#animation ` to have `position: absolute;`

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i was also wondering, is there a way to clear the interval, to stop the animation, with the code example you've provided? i've done it when it's something like var timer = setInterval and then call timer to clear it